# Radio Button active color in flutter doesn't work

Tags: flutter

So I was trying to make two radio button input which has value as a male and a female. When I press the radio button, It did print the value, however, the radio button active color doesn't change or remains white. When I pressed the radio button, the activecolor is set to be black, when I press it.

```
Scaffold(
          body:Container(
                            margin:EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40, 100, 80, 0),
                            child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                child:Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: [
                                   Radio(
                              groupValue:genderController.text,
                              value:"Male",
                              activeColor: Colors.black,
                              onChanged:(value){
                                setState(() {
                                  genderController.text=value;
                                  print(genderController.text);
                                  
                                });
                              }
                            ),
                              Text("Male"
                                ,style:TextStyle(fontSize: 10),textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                              ),
                                ],
                                )
                              ),
                             
                             Container(
                                child:Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: [
                                Container(
                                child: Radio(
                                  groupValue:genderController.text,
                              value:"Female",
                              activeColor: Colors.black,
                               onChanged:(value){
                                setState(() {
                                  genderController.text=value;
                                  print(genderController.text);
                                });
                              }
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text("Female"
                            ,style:TextStyle(fontSize: 10,),textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                          ),
                            ],
                            )
                          ),
                        ],
                     ),
     ));
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3299H.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8rWE.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the link :
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Radio-class.html

```
//Variable of your state 
String _yourGroupValue = "Male"; //This would show you the pre-selected

Radio(
      groupValue:_yourGroupValue,
      value:"Male",
      activeColor: Colors.black,
      onChanged:(value){
      print(value);
      setState(() {
        _yourGroupValue = value;
      });
}),
```

Do the same thing for you another Radio button.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is linked to the fact that your value is not set dynamicaly.

You have a working exemple here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Radio-class.html